# Referencing different assemblies in different configurations

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, reference

Before asking, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284017/two-different-assembly-versions-the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208084/how-to-use-a-different-assembly-name-for-different-configurations) threads. No help there.

I am using Visual Studio 2003 (this is mandated by my employer) but I guess answers to later versions of VS might also be useful.

So, imagine I have two .Net projects: A - which is a class library and B - which is an application. In B I click **Add Reference**, go to the **Projects** tab and choose A. In this scenario the debug version of B will reference the debug version of A, and the release version of B will use the release version of A. Now imagine that instead of project A I just have two assemblies - aD.dll and a.dll. I don't have any project that creates these. What I want to do is enforce that Debug version of B reference aD.dll, and the release version of B reference a.dll
***Question 1: How do I do this?***

When I want to reference some dll, I go to **add reference** -> **Browse** and browse my dll. But I need to specify not the full path, but the relative path.
***Question 2: How do I do this?***

This is an emergency, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't do this through the IDE, but you can do it by hacking the .csproj file by hand:

If you've already got a reference to, say, `a.dll`:

```
<Reference Include="a">...</Reference>
```

...then try a pair of conditions as follows:

```
<Reference Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'" Include="a">...</Reference>
<Reference Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" Include="aD">...</Reference>
```

**Edit:** Here's an explanation of what you can put inside a `<Reference>` element: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. And in this case can I specify the relative path like  **Include = "../../Assemblies/Debug/aD.dll"** ?

Comment: The `Include=` is the name of the DLL (without the extension), but you can put what you like inside the `<HintPath>` element. The IDE should have already provided a `<HintPath>`.